pass variable into server action form NextJs 14
Can I pass a variable into a server action that is being used in a form?
this works:
//client component
 <form action={test}
      >

//server action
export const test = async (formData: FormData) => {

  console.log(formData);
}

But this doesn't
//client component
const companyID = 1;
return (
 <form action={test(companyID)}
      >
...

)
//server action
export const test = async (formData: FormData, companyID) => {

  console.log(formData, companyID);
}


Yes, you have a few of options.

Change this <form action={test(companyID)} to <form action={(event) => test(event, companyID)} - you may need to check the types there, I think the event is going to be SubmitEvent or FormEvent rather than FormData

What you're actually doing with test(companyID) is calling the function during rendering, without any action happening. Here's some additional docs on this if you're interested: https://react.dev/learn/responding-to-events#:~:text=Pitfall

What you'll more typically see, because you might end up doing other logic after the response from the server action (showing success, failure etc) is this:

...

const companyID = 1;

async function submitHandler(formData){

  console.log(formData, companyID)
  const serverResponse = await serverAction(formData, companyID)

  //Do something with the server response
}

...

return ( 
    <form action={submitHandler}>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Something..."/>
    </form>
  )



I think the above can be improved on. I'm personally not a fan of having variables that aren't parameters to the function directly. It makes the functions impure. You have a third option of setting a hidden companyId field with the value, and then it would all be in the formData. I don't know where that companyID comes from in your code, but I'm guessing it's from a dynamic route.

export default Page({params}){

const {companyID} = params;

async function submitHandler(formData){
  //Now formData has companyID directly in it.

  const serverResponse = await serverAction(formData)

  //Do something with the server response
}

return ( 
    <form action={submitHandler}>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Something..."/>
      <input type="hidden" value={companyID} name="companyID"/>
    </form>
  )



I guess its the default server action pattern. Its defined in the nextjs documentation. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#examples
